# How do I use android.support.transition?

Tags: android, transition, compatibility

I want to run my app, which uses **transitions** on an android device with **Jelly Bean 4.2.2, API 17**. In the build.gradle:app targetSdkVerion is set to 24, minSdkVersion to 16.

When launching the app on my device I get the error `Could not find class android.transition.Transition`

On Android Developers theres a package called **android.support.transition** mentioned, but I don't know how to use it, when I insert it in my build.gradle I get an error, "Could not find com.android.support:transitions:24.1.1.

**Do I need to change the values, and if so, how?**

My build.gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "user.example"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:transition:24.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download or update support library from SDK Manager. This is link from Android Developer website :

[Setup Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html#choosing)

Then you can use the support transition library. Note that if you want to use the TransitionManager class from this support library, be sure to import the support library version ('android.support.transition.TransitionManager')

Comment: Well, thank for your answer, I've updated my SDK Manager, and added TransitionManager to the build.gradle, but I still get the error "Could not find com.android.support:transition:24.1.1."